# Why does a route work locally but returns an error when deployed on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have deployed a ruby-on-rails app on heroku, however, a route that works locally doesnt work when deployed. This is what I mean, http://localhost:3000/seller_home/index works fine while http://system.heroku.app/seller_home/index doesn't work.

Comment: We need to see the error. Anyway, the reason could be the data that you have in the databases is different. One of them breaks your code :)

Comment: If you run `heroku logs --tail` in your console you should be able to see the issue.  To see more about Heroku log options you can read here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging